# mysqli deletion

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

    if (intval($_GET['page']) == 0) {
        redirect_to("staff.php");
    }

    $id = mysqli_prep($_GET['page']);



        $query3 = "DELETE FROM page WHERE id = {$id}, LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query3);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
            redirect_to("staff.php");
        } else {
            // Deletion Failed

            echo $id ."<br />" . $query3 . "<br />" . $result . "<p>Subject
           deletion failed.</p>";
            echo "<p>" . mysqli_error() . "</p>";
            echo "<a href=\"staff.php\">Return to Main Page</a>";
        }
      //  Keep on working Edit:2#
      mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id = 11 ");
     //- Works 
     Edit 3# 
       $id = $_GET['page'];
        echo "<p>" . $id ."</p>";
            $query3 ="DELETE FROM pages WHERE id = {$id} ";
                    mysqli_query($connection,$query3 );
                    // Still Works  -- YaY for working backwards
   // Edit #4 By "now it might be obvious what my error was "pages" not "page"
       // Thanks everyone - And thank you for telling me about the error page
        // My defense - newbie- Anyway Lesson from this - working backwards 
        // Takes a while, Error checking Fast!!!!!!
?>
```

$connection is started and selected. The $id is selected successfully, and the $page = $id, but it still will not work. $query 3 seems fine, but Deletion failed. I don't have any idea what the error is.  Thanks for any help in advance.
-Josh  Edit Check Error Check

Comment: Made it less complicated, and edited ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't have any idea what the error is.

That's because you didn't check.  Every time you prepare or execute a query, you need to check for errors.  Most of the functions in mysqli return `FALSE` if they encounter an error.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query3);
if ($result === false) {
    trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);
    header("Location: /error.php");
    exit;
}
```

The failure to check for error cases is one of the most common blunders committed by database programmers.

Comment: I did not even know about the error log. I Thank you very kindly. I will keep updating.

Comment: @WackyMole actually, `trigger_error()` is way more useful than error_log()

Comment: @YourCommonSense, thanks, I have changed it in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma after the ID:

```
$query3 = "DELETE FROM page WHERE id = {$id}, LIMIT 1";
                                            ^ remove this
```

Comment: @WackyMole What does `mysqli_error($connection)` give you after the delete query?

Comment: @WackyMole You are using `pages` in the working statements and `page` in the non-working one. Is that just a typo or one of the causes of your problems?

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($page == get_page_by_id($id)) {
```

== for comparison

=== to compare the value and the cast

```
$val = true;
if ($val === true) {
    echo "\$val is bool(true)";
}

if ($val == "true") {
    echo "\$val matches value";
}


if ($val === "true") {
// this will never happen
} else {
echo "\$val doesnt === \"true\"";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be "==" but I don't think the if statement is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

try to use `php_flag display_errors on` in your .htaccess
this will allow you to see and identify php errors.